# App navigation in React Native : maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ios, react-native, atom-editor

I'm using ReactNative to create an iOS app. But I encountered an error I don't know how to fix.

I wanted to create a button for navigating to another scene. I followed [Dark Army's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOQDrI4V7Z4) on RN navigation and used the [source code provided](https://github.com/darkarmyIN/DARNNavigator). I double checked everything and all seemed fine. But the error I mentioned pops up.

Here's the code I have done so far:

**Index.ios.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

var Navigation = require('./DARNNavigator');

class QayProject extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigation></Navigation>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF5E7',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('QayProject', () => QayProject);
```

**DARNNavigator:**

```
'use strict';

import React , {Component} from 'react';
import{
  View,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';


const FirstPage = require('./FirstPage');
const SecondPage = require('./SecondPage');
class DARNNavigator extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var initialRouteID = 'first';
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={{flex:1}}
        initialRoute={{id: initialRouteID}}
        renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}/>
    );
  }

  navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'first':
        return (<FirstPage navigator={navigator} route={route} title="FirstPage"/>);
      case 'second':
        return (<SecondPage navigator={navigator} route={route} title="SecondPage"/>);

    }
  }
}


module.exports = DARNNavigator;
```

**FirstPage:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import{
      View,
      Navigator,
      Button,
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet
    } from 'react-native';

    export default class FirstPage extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={ id:'first' }
      }
      render() {
        return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

        <Button
          onPress={this.props.navigator.push({ id:'second' })}
          title="Next"
          color="#FFB200"
        />

        </View>

        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
    });

    module.exports = FirstPage;
```

**SecondPage:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export default class SecondPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state={
    id:'second'
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
      Hello!
      </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

module.exports = SecondPage;
```

Comment: Excellent first post. Very clear, very nicely formatted. Well done.  If you haven't seen the site's [2 Minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look. There are a lot of neat things to do here.

Comment: Thanks! You guys are awesome. :)

Comment: In my opinion, and as @appsthatmatter has suggested, built-in Navigation is what you should use. Take a look at his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to follow the official guide of React Native and use the built-in `Navigator` component.

[Using Navigators React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-navigators.html)

I never saw that error, but if it will come after a lot of navigation steps, you should take a look at the [`resetTo`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#resetto) function. It will clear the navigation stack. This makes sense for example when you are navigating back to the home screen of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use that library. They don't even have ONE single star on Github (not that it's the measure of a library's worth, I'm just saying there are more proven libraries available). The best and most straightforward I've found so far is "react-native-navigation" (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation). A lot of people like "react-native-router-flux" as well but I personally don't.

Sorry, I don't have time to read the code right now, I may later. But my suggestion for now is to try out react-native-navigation. It's seriously amazing.

Comment: I couldn't run the program. The RCTBridge files somehow was not found.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try to make a Facebook login and add the required libraries? This is a common error when trying to do this. To learn how to navigate, what I did was download an example app using the Navigator library I wanted to use. You can find one using react-native-navigation here:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/master/example